# Problema con multiples ventanas con tkinter en python

Tags: python, tkinter, ventana

Tengo mi interfaz grafica en python usando tkinter;

[image: VentanaPrincipal]

[image: VentanaSecundaria]

[image: Ventanahija de la Secundaria]

Mi Codigo es el siguiente:

```
    from tkinter import *
    
    #Funciones de los Botones de la pantalla Principal
    def ventanaSeleccionar():
        ventanaPrincipal.withdraw()
        global ventanaSeleccionar
        ventanaSeleccionar = Toplevel(ventanaPrincipal)
        ventanaSeleccionar.title("Seleccionar Archivo")
        ventanaSeleccionar.geometry("400x150")
        etiqueta7 = Label(ventanaSeleccionar, text="Ruta: ", font=("Comic Sans MS", 10)).place(x=80, y=40)
        cuadroText = Entry(ventanaSeleccionar).place(x=120, y=40)
        boton5 = Button(ventanaSeleccionar, text="Seleccionar", font=("Comic Sans MS", 8)).place(x=110, y=80)
        boton6 = Button(ventanaSeleccionar, text="Regresar", font=("Comic Sans MS", 8), command=ventanaSeleccionar.destroy).place(x=210, y=80)
    
        ventanaSeleccionar.mainloop()
    
    def ventanaGestionar():
        ventanaPrincipal.withdraw()
        global ventanaGestionar
        ventanaGestionar = Toplevel(ventanaPrincipal)
        ventanaGestionar.title("Gestionar Cursos")
        ventanaGestionar.geometry("350x360")
        boton7 = Button(ventanaGestionar, text="Listar Cursos", font=("Comic Sans MS", 8), command=ventanaListar).place(x=135, y=50)
        boton8 = Button(ventanaGestionar, text="Agregar Curso", font=("Comic Sans MS", 8)).place(x=130, y=100)
        boton9 = Button(ventanaGestionar, text="Editar Curso", font=("Comic Sans MS", 8)).place(x=135, y=150)
        boton10 = Button(ventanaGestionar, text="Eliminar Curso", font=("Comic Sans MS", 8)).place(x=130, y=200)
        boton11 = Button(ventanaGestionar, text="Regresar", font=("Comic Sans MS", 8), command=volverVentanaGestionar_ventanaPrincipal).place(x=145, y=250)
    
        ventanaGestionar.mainloop()
```

Aca es donde yo creo que tengo el error pero no se cual excatamente ya que creo que oculto la ventana y por eso ya no la puedo abrir de nuevo supongo que me falta algun deiconify()

```
    #Ventanas de la opcion Gestionar Curso
    def ventanaListar():
        ventanaGestionar.withdraw()
        global ventanaListar
        ventanaListar = Toplevel(ventanaGestionar)
        ventanaListar.title("Listar Cursos")
        ventanaListar.geometry("490x380")
        boton12 = Button(ventanaListar, text="Regresar", font=("Comic Sans MS", 8), command=volverVentanaListar_ventanaGestionar).place(x=415, y=335)
    
        ventanaListar.mainloop()
    
    #Funcion que regresa a las ventanas anteriores 
    def volverVentanaGestionar_ventanaPrincipal():
        ventanaPrincipal.deiconify()
        ventanaGestionar.withdraw()
    
    def volverVentanaListar_ventanaGestionar():
        ventanaGestionar.deiconify()
        ventanaListar.withdraw()
    
    global ventanaPrincipal #volvemos global la ventana
    
    #Crea ventanas
    ventanaPrincipal = Tk()
    
    #Titulo de la ventana
    ventanaPrincipal.title("Practica 1")
    
    #Tamaño de la ventans
    ventanaPrincipal.geometry("450x350")
    
    #Agrega etiquetas a la pantalla Principal
    etiqueta1 = Label(ventanaPrincipal, text="Nombre del Curso: ", font=("Comic Sans MS", 10)).place(x=25, y=10)
    etiqueta2 = Label(ventanaPrincipal, text="Lab. Lenguajes Formales y de Programación", font=("Comic Sans MS", 10)).place(x=140, y=10)
    etiqueta3 = Label(ventanaPrincipal, text="Nombre del Estudiante: ", font=("Comic Sans MS", 10)).place(x=25, y=40)
    etiqueta4 = Label(ventanaPrincipal, text="Alejandro López ", font=("Comic Sans MS", 10)).place(x=170, y=40)
    etiqueta5 = Label(ventanaPrincipal, text="Carné del Estudiante: ", font=("Comic Sans MS", 10)).place(x=25, y=70)
    etiqueta6 = Label(ventanaPrincipal, text="201709469 ", font=("Comic Sans MS", 10)).place(x=160, y=70)
    
    #Agrega botones a la pantalla Principal
    boton1 = Button(ventanaPrincipal, text="Cargar Archivo", font=("Comic Sans MS", 8), command=ventanaSeleccionar).place(x=180, y=140)
    boton2 = Button(ventanaPrincipal, text="Gestionar Cursos", font=("Comic Sans MS", 8), command=ventanaGestionar).place(x=176, y=180)
    boton3 = Button(ventanaPrincipal, text="Conteo de Creditos", font=("Comic Sans MS", 8)).place(x=172, y=220)
    boton4 = Button(ventanaPrincipal, text="Salir", font=("Comic Sans MS", 8), command=ventanaPrincipal.destroy).place(x=205, y=260)
    
    ventanaPrincipal.mainloop()
```

bueno el problema es que cuando de doy a la opcion gestionar curso, luego a listar curso me despliega todo correcto, luego regreso al menu principal y quiero volver hacer el mismo procedimiento por segunda ves ya no me abre la ventana de listar curso es decir la tercera foto ya no aparece.

Comment: Si no he contado mal, usas cuatro `.mainloop()` cuando no deberías llamar al bucle principal nada más que una vez y en el hilo principal. No es _"reentrante"_, esto es, que no puedes llamar a un mainloop mientras estás dentro de otro. Te recomiendo que uses las funciones para "crear" ventanas, no para "ejecutarlas". No puedo ayudarte mucho más ya que hace mucho que no uso tkinter.

Comment: Como ya te han dicho borrá todos los mainloop, salvo el de la ventana principal y cambia el nombre de las funciones, eliminando la palabra ventana por ejemplo, ya que después estás usando ese mismo nombre para declarar las ventanas, con eso ya debería andar.

Comment: muchas gracias si se soluciono el problema mil mil gracias justamente con lo que me dijeron borrando los .mainloop() y cambiando el nombre a las funciones